# Запись времени в SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql

Нужно, чтобы при авторизации пользователя параллельно шла запись времени (при авторизации) в таблицу SQL столбца Time_Connect. И при деавторизации тоже записывалась в столбец Time_Disconnect.

Имеется следующий код:

```
private void mAuth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String loginUser = authLogin.Text;
            String passUser = authPassword.Text;

            DB db = new DB();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `WorketTableLog` WHERE `Auth_Login` = @uL AND `Auth_Password` = @uP", db.getCon());
            command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;

            MySqlCommand insertDate = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `WorketTableLog` `Time_Connect` Values ('" + DateTime.Now + "')", db.getCon());
            MySqlCommand updateDate = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `WorketTableLog` SET `Time_Connect` = '" + DateTime.Now + "'", db.getCon());
            command.Parameters.Add("@dateTime", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            //insertDate = "UPDATE WorketTableLog SET Time_Connect = '" + DateTime.Now + "'";


            adapter.SelectCommand = updateDate;
            adapter.SelectCommand = insertDate;
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                labelLogin.Visible = false;
                hello.Visible = true;
                labelPassword.Visible = false;
                authLogin.Visible = false;
                authPassword.Visible = false;
                mAuth.Visible = false;
                mExit.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Неправильный логин или пароль.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: @r3pl1c4nt, да.

Comment: @r3pl1c4nt MySqlCommand insertDate = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `WorketTableLog` WHERE `Time_Connect` Values ('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')", db.getCon());, ввел, но не сработало :(

Возможно ошибка в запросе, но хз

Comment: @r3pl1c4nt - в коде `MySqlDataAdapter`, `MySqlCommand`, `MySqlDbType`. Как по вашему, какая это БД? Мне кажется, что всё-таки MySql.

Comment: Что значит "да"? Sql Server (aka ms sql) и MySql - это две совершенно разных СУБД!

Comment: Шло третье десятилетие двадцать первого века, в базу продолжали уходить непараметризованные запросы с sql-инъекциями... :(

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да да :)

Comment: В общем, спасибо за конструктивный диалог, @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос, исправьте форматирование, добавьте деталей, если хотите получить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно непонятно, зачем вы пытаетесь использовать `DataAdapter`, который предназначен для работы с множеством строк (набором данных). Поэтому выкинем его полностью (и `DataTable` тоже).

Далее, я предлагаю убить двух здоровенных зайцев одним запросом `Update`. Вставляем время пользователю с определённым логином и паролем. Если запрос прошёл успешно, значит такой пользователь есть. Таким образом мы и убедились в его наличии, и данные вставили.

```
void Login(string login, string pass)
{
    string sql = "UPDATE `WorketTableLog` SET `Time_Connect` = @time WHERE `Auth_Login` = @login AND `Auth_Password` = @pass";

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("time", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            command.Parameters.Add("login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login;
            command.Parameters.Add("pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;

            int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rowsAffected == 1)
            {
                // Успешно вставили время.
                // Это значит в таблице есть пользователь с таким логином и паролем.
            }
            else
            {
                // Неправильный логин или пароль.
                // Или ошибка в работе с БД.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При деавторизации, я полагаю, нет смысла проверять пароль. Ведь мы уже знаем, что этот пользователь существует. Просто обновляем в таблице столбец "Time_Disconnect".

```
void Logout(string login)
{
    string sql = "UPDATE `WorketTableLog` SET `Time_Disconnect` = @time WHERE `Auth_Login` = @login";

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("time", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            command.Parameters.Add("login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login;

            int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rowsAffected == 1)
            {
                // Успешно вставили время.
            }
            else
            {
                // Ошибка в работе с БД.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

А теперь прописные истины:

- освобождайте ресурсы, оборачивая их в оператор `using` (или вызывая метод `Dispose`),
- используйте параметризованные запросы, это защитит от sql-инъекций.

Желательно переделать код на асинхронный: используйте `OpenAsync()`, `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`.

Не храните в БД пароли. Вместо этого храните хеши, причём обязательно с солью. Рекомендую к прочтению: [Adding Salt to Hashing: A Better Way to Store Passwords](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/).

---

Ещё замечание. Я не вижу большого смысла в таком хранении времени. Ведь оно перетирается при каждом новом входе юзера.
Вероятно, вам следует создать отдельную *историческую* таблицу (связанную через внешний ключ с этой), в которой будет храниться время за все сеансы пользователя.